# Getting the highest Parent Account in Salesforce Hierarchy via SOQL/APEX

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I am trying to get the highest level of parent account in an Account Hierarchy in Salesforce via Apex and SOQL. 
I want to create and `MAP<Id, Set<Account>>` hierarchy in my Apex class to where the highest parent account's `Id` is the Id in the Map while all the child accounts (or at any level) are in the `Set`.

I have written the following recursive function to do this but I can't get all the child Accounts in there for the top most parent account.

```
public class AccountsHierarchy{

    public Map<Id, Account> allChildAccounts {get; private set;}
    private Map<String, Set<Account>> parentAccountMap {get; set;}
    private List<Account> childAccounts {get; set;}


    public AccountsHierarchy(){

        allChildAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([
                SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.ParentId
                FROM Account
                WHERE ParentId != NULL
        ]);
        childAccounts = new List<Account>();
        System.debug(allChildAccounts);
        parentAccountMap = getParentAccountMap();
        System.debug(parentAccountMap);

    }

    private String getParentAccountId(String childAccountId){

        Account localAccount = allChildAccounts.get(childAccountId);
        if(localAccount.Parent.ParentId != null) {

            childAccounts.add(localAccount);
            return getParentAccountId(localAccount.ParentId);

        }else
            return localAccount.ParentId;

    }

    public Map<String, Set<Account>> getParentAccountMap(){

        Map<String, Set<Account>> parentAccounts = new Map<String, Set<Account>>();
        for(String childAccountId:allChildAccounts.keySet()){

            //childAccounts.clear();

            String parentAccountId = getParentAccountId(childAccountId);

            if(parentAccountId != null){

                if(parentAccounts.containsKey(parentAccountId)){
                    Set<Account> childAccountsFromMap = parentAccounts.get(parentAccountId);
                    childAccountsFromMap.addAll(childAccounts);
                    parentAccounts.remove(parentAccountId);
                    parentAccounts.put(parentAccountId, childAccountsFromMap);
                } else {
                    parentAccounts.put(parentAccountId, new Set<Account>(childAccounts));
                }
            }
        }

        return parentAccounts;

    }
}
```

Comment: Which child accounts are missing?  Is it all accounts from a specific level in the hierarchy?

Comment: All I get are the child accounts at first level. I want to look for all the child accounts from any level in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach to this would be, in my opinion, to create a hidden field to store the Id of the account on the top of the hierarchy, and fill it with a trigger, process or workflow rule.

Scenario 1:

1. Top account is created
2. Child account is created, but parent account is not related yet.
3. User remembers that the accounts are related, and fills the "parent account" field.
4. Have the system update the "account on top of the hierarchy" field with either the value of the same field on the parent record (if it isn't blank) or fill it with the parent record's Id.

Scenario 2:

1. Top account and child account are created.
2. User creates a third account that will now act as the parent for the other two.
3. User fills the "parent account" on the old parent account record with the new top account created.
4. Have the system update the "account on top of the hierarchy" field on the child records, if the account is the new parent or not (checking the same field, again).

Scenario 3:

1. Top account, middle account and bottom account are created.
2. User creates another account that will sit between two of those.
3. User fills the "parent account" of the new account with the referente of any of the accounts currently in the database.
4. If the account selected as parent is the top one, check if the "account on top of the hierarchy" field of the parent record is empty. If it is not, then the created account should copy the parent's account field. If it is empty, then the parent account is the top account, and the system should copy the account Id instead.

These should cover the most common scenarios, I believe. That way you will not have to worry about hitting governor limits when searching for the account on top.

It might be a good thing to do a little research if there is such situation where multiple accounts are linked through the ParentId field. If there aren't that many levels, then you'll probably be fine using the query inside the loop as an exception, because it is indeed simpler than doing all this. But if you don't know how many accounts can be nested or the business requires that the accounts are nested, then it might be a good idea to invest some time in this kind of solution.

Comment: Actually, this is very neat the way you explained it. I forgot to mention in my last post about there's an external system integrated with Salesforce and it keeps it's own record of heirarchy and top most parent account ids in the system. And I used that (by importing that id info as a custom field) and do the similar iteration. I have had success with this this issue.

Comment: Although, if there wasn't any involvement of the external system with Salesforce Accounts I'd definitely prefer what you have suggested, and in a way I am following the similar approach except I don't have to copy the value of top most parent on the child accounts it's done by the external system itself. Rest of the process is the same.

Answer (score 2):

I am working on a similar issue I found alot of help and a solution to this using the following website

https://jdspaceit.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/traversing-through-an-accounts-hierarchy-in-apex/

```
    //find highest parent account from a child
public id findTopLevelParent(account a) {
    Boolean isTopLevelAccount = false;
    account acct = new account();
    id currAcctId = a.id;

    while (!isTopLevelAccount) {

        acct = [select Id, ParentId From Account where Id = :currAcctId limit 1];
        if (acct.ParentID != null) {
            currAcctId = acct.ParentID;
        } else {
            isTopLevelAccount = true;
        }
    }

    return currAcctId;   
}
```

From that website I Got this piece of code working.

**Update:**
As for the Map part, [heres](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266224/how-do-i-roll-up-an-account-hierarchy-and-keep-all-children-in-sync) the link to the flushed out method from that link I shared earlier.

I do not know if this is the best solution, So definetly open to critique

Comment: Do you think it is the best way to do this? I have the possible data set of 10,000 Accounts and since the query is in the loop, this will definitely fail at some point due to Governor limits.

Comment: Also the point is not just get the Top Level Parent but also to create a Map using the Parent Id with the Set of Child Accounts .

Comment: @AnasRashid yeah it definitely will flirt the line of governor limits haha.  I Updated my post to include my other thread that is on the same topic. That method works but its definitely resource hog. I am looking for better ways to accomplish this as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most aggressive SOQL query available to find the top level Account from any starting Account Id:

```
select ParentId, Parent.ParentId, Parent.Parent.ParentId,
Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId, Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId from Account where
Id='0014000000phijeAAA'
```

Here is an example with the maximum of 6 Parent Ids returned. If you still have not reached the top ParentId=NULL then you must recurse on the last returned Parent Id and run the query again until you get there.

```
<queryResponse>
    <result xsi:type="QueryResult">
        <done>true</done>
        <queryLocator xsi:nil="true"/>
        <records xsi:type="sf:sObject">
            <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
            <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
            <sf:ParentId>0014000000YqM2lAAF</sf:ParentId>
            <sf:Parent xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                <sf:ParentId>0014000000YqK8sAAF</sf:ParentId>
                <sf:Parent xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                    <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                    <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <sf:ParentId>0011W000024Jv1NQAS</sf:ParentId>
                    <sf:Parent xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                        <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                        <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                        <sf:ParentId>0014000000YqLtxAAF</sf:ParentId>
                        <sf:Parent xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                            <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                            <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                            <sf:ParentId>0011W000024JvBRQA0</sf:ParentId>
                            <sf:Parent xsi:type="sf:sObject">
                                <sf:type>Account</sf:type>
                                <sf:Id xsi:nil="true"/>
                                <sf:ParentId>0014000000YqMGjAAN</sf:ParentId>
                            </sf:Parent>
                        </sf:Parent>
                    </sf:Parent>
                </sf:Parent>
            </sf:Parent>
        </records>
        <size>1</size>
    </result>
</queryResponse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly answering for my own satisfaction.

Working with a query that has no filters is always a bit risky. If you have more than 200k records for a given object, having no filters would all but guarantee that you get a query exception for a non-selective query. You'd hit the 50k row limit before that (unless you're working with a batch class).

I'd probably tackle this in two steps.
The first step is using anonymous apex to push down the Ids at the top of the hierarchy down to child records, doing multiple runs until the main query returns 0 rows.

```java
List<Account> accountsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

// Not wild about having "ParentId = null" as a filter, but we need something like
//   that to be able to get the top-level accounts to feed the rest of the process
// This loop can be commented out after the first run (or leave it in, your choice)
for(Account topLevel :[SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Top_Level_Account_Is_Set__c = false AND ParentId = null]) {
    topLevel.Top_Level_Account_Is_Set__c = true;
    topLevel.Top_Level_Account_Id__c = topLevel.Id;

    accountsToUpdate.add(topLevel);
}

update accountsToUpdate;

for(Account child :[SELECT Id, ParentId, Parent.Top_Level_Account_Id__c FROM Account WHERE Top_Level_Account_Is_Set__c = false AND Parent.Top_Level_Account_Is_Set__c = true LIMIT 9000]) {
    // Take the top level account from our immediate parent
    child.Top_Level_Account_Id__c = child.Parent.Top_Level_Account_Id__c;

    // Set a flag so we don't process this record again
    child.Top_Level_Account_Is_Set__c = true;

    accountsToUpdate.add(child);
}

// No need to check if a list is empty before performing DML
// When an empty list is passed, Salesforce just doesn't perform any DML
update accountsToUpdate;
```

Each time you run this, it'll propagate the top-level information down one more level. If you have a particularly wide hierarchy, it's possible that it can take multiple runs to work through a given level. The nice thing about the way the child query is structured (we only pull children that haven't been processed and whose parent *has been processed*) is that we don't have to worry about any additional state. That information alone is sufficient to identify records that can be processed. This'll also work for orgs that have over 50k Accounts (though query selectivity would eventually become an issue).

Eventually you'll work your way through your accounts. From there, building the list of child accounts is trivial (setting aside issues with query selectivity and the query rows limit).

```java
Map<Id, Set<Id>> hierarchyAccountsByTopLevelId = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();

for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, Top_Level_Account_Id__c FROM Account]){

    // Initialize the value for a given key if this is our first time encountering
    //   the key
    // Doing it this way, we can avoid using an "else"
    if(!hierarchyAccountsByTopLevelId.containsKey(acct.Top_Level_Account_Id__c)) {
        hierarchyAccountsByTopLevelId.put(acct.Top_Level_Account_Id__c, new Set<Id>());
    }

    // Non-primitive types are stored by reference, so we can .get() from the map
    //   and then act directly on the result
    hierarchyAccountsByTopLevelId.get(acct.Top_Level_Account_Id__c).add(acct.Id);
}

// This does mean the top-level account is contained in the set of its descendants
// If you don't want that, then it's just another simple loop to get rid of that
for(Id topLevelId :hierarchyAccountsByTopLevelId.keySet()) {
    hierarchyAccountsByTopLevelId.get(topLevelId).remove(topLevelId);
}
```

You'd then want to have a trigger or a flow to maintain this data as accounts are inserted/updated/deleted.

If you have less than 50k accounts and want to do things in a single shot (i.e. re-calculate it every time), then you've got a bit more work to do. Basically, it means that you have to build the record hierarchy in-memory, yourself. After you do that, you can use recursion to go top-down to build your map.

```java
// We need to be able to go from a parent record to its children
// While you could use a parent-child subquery for this, you'd quickly run into
//   the query row limit
// A Map<Id, List<Account>> should do nicely (as we can build the map no matter
//   what order we handle the Accounts in)
Map<Id, List<Account>> childAccountsByParentId = new Map<Id, List<Account>>();

for(Account acct :[SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Account]) {
    // Don't need to worry about top-level accounts here
    // They'll just end up being put in the list with a null key
    // Actually, pretty handy for knowing where to start our recursion later
    if(!childAccountsByParentId.containsKey(acct.ParentId)) {
        childAccountsByParentId.put(acct.ParentId, new List<Account>());
    }

    childAccountsByParentId.get(acct.ParentId).add(acct);
}

// Need to do a bit more preparation
Map<Id, Set<Id>> results = new Map<Id, Set<Id>>();
Map<Id, Id> topLevelIdByParentId = new Map<Id, Id>();
List<Account> topLevelChildren = new List<Account>();

// Top-level accounts are those under the null key
for(Account topLevel :childAccountsByParentId.get(null)) {
    // Taking care of initializing map values now so we don't need to worry about
    //   it when we recurse
    results.put(topLevel.Id, new Set<Id>());
    topLevelIdByParentId.put(topLevel.Id, topLevel.Id);
    topLevelChildren.addAll(childAccountsByParentId.get(topLevel.Id));
}

recurse(results, topLevelChildren);

public void recurse(Map<Id, Set<Id>> hierarchyAccountIdsByTopLevelId, List<Account> accounts) {
    // base case
    if(accounts.isEmpty()) { return; }

    List<Account> nextLevelAccounts = new List<Account>();

    // Note that this only works because the setup we did for all of this ensures
    //   that we'll get accounts in order of their hierarchy level
    for(Account acct :accounts) {
        Id topLevelId = topLevelIdByParentId.get(acct.ParentId);

        // We need to take our parent's top level id and make it available
        //   for when we iterate over this account's children
        topLevelIdByParentId.put(acct.Id, topLevelId);

        // This is the step that actually builds the end result
        hierarchyAccountIdsByTopLevelId.get(topLevelId).add(acct.Id);

        nextLevelAccounts.addAll(childAccountsByParentId.get(acct.Id));
    }

    // Onto the children!
    // This could be done inside the loop to save 2 lines of code...
    // The decision of in or out of the loop is yours to make
    resurse(hierarchyAccountIdsByTopLevelId, nextLevelAccounts);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

## Use below code to get account to topmost account map , though this is also a kind of recursion but it will reduce the SOQL by 80% :

public static Map<Id,Id> getTopMostParent(List AccountIds){

```
    Map<Id,Id> accountToParentAccMap_current = new Map<Id,Id>();        
    
    for(Account acc : [select parent.id, parent.parent.id, parent.parent.parent.id, parent.parent.parent.parent.id,parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.Id from Account where id in :AccountIds]){            
        if(acc.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.Id != null){        //check for 5th parent
            //add accid to list for recursion                
            accountToParentAccMap_current.put(acc.id,getTopMostParent(new List<Id>{acc.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.Id}).values()[0]);                
        }else if(acc.parent.parent.parent.parent.id != null){        //check for 4th parent                
            accountToParentAccMap_current.put(acc.id,acc.parent.parent.parent.parent.id);
        }else if(acc.parent.parent.parent.id != null){                //check for 3rd parent                
            accountToParentAccMap_current.put(acc.id,acc.parent.parent.parent.id);
        }else if(acc.parent.parent.id != null){                        //check for 2nd parent                
            accountToParentAccMap_current.put(acc.id,acc.parent.parent.id);
        }else if(acc.parent.id != null){                            //check for 1st parent                
            accountToParentAccMap_current.put(acc.id,acc.parent.id);
        }else{                                                        // no parent account                 
            accountToParentAccMap_current.put(acc.id,acc.id);    // put the same account id
        }
    }        
    return accountToParentAccMap_current;
}
```

Comment: The explanation is as important as the solution itself. It's also important to note that this approach is limited to hierarchies that are at most 5 levels deep. For hierarchies of arbitrary depth, the "mark the top, and propagate that information down" approach suggested by Renato Oliveira is the main approach to take.

Answer (score -2):

I fixed your code try to run this. This works.

```java
public class AccountsHierarchy{

    public Map<Id, Account> allChildAccounts {get; private set;}
    public Map<String, Set<Id>> parentAccountMap = new Map<String,SET<Id>>();



    public AccountsHierarchy(){

        allChildAccounts = new Map<Id, Account>([
                SELECT Id,Name, ParentId, Parent.ParentId,(select id from contacts)
                FROM Account
                WHERE ParentId != NULL
        ]);
         for(String childAccountId:allChildAccounts.keySet()){
             
                String parentAccountId = getParentAccountId(childAccountId,new SET<Id>());
        }
        
        System.debug(parentAccountMap);

    }

    public String getParentAccountId(String childAccountId, SET<Id> childIds){
        SET<Id> childAccSET = childIds;
        Account localAccount = allChildAccounts.get(childAccountId);
       
        if(localAccount.Parent.ParentId != null) {
            
            childAccSET.add(localAccount.Id);
            
            return getParentAccountId(localAccount.ParentId,childAccSET);

        }else
        {
         
            if(!parentAccountMap.containsKey(localAccount.ParentId))
            {
              
                parentAccountMap.put(localAccount.ParentId,childAccSET);
                
                return null; 
            }
            else{
                parentAccountMap.get(localAccount.ParentId).addAll(childAccSET);
               
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Again, the explanation is as important as the solution. Please [edit] your answer to go over what the changes you made were and how it fixes the issue.

Comment: The subquery for Contacts is unnecessary (and consumes query rows).

Comment: This code also doesn't appear to fix the issue at all. You'd need to have a hierarchy at least 3 levels deep to get anything stored in the set of child Ids (otherwise the map would just contain an empty set). Further, hiding the addition to the child id set behind the check for `localAccount.Parent.ParentId != null` ensures that any hierarchy >= 3 levels deep will be missing the Ids of the second level of the hierarchy. This is the same major mistake that the original code makes.