# Find Ultimate Parent using account Id, require trigger based approach

Tags: apex

Recently, I was being asked to write a code to find ultimate account hierarchy. Account hierarchy can be of 30+ levels. I suggested them 3 approach:

1. Batch class approach querying all accounts and creating a map
2. Recursive function approach having a soql inside for loop.
3. Text field created on account which is getting populated on before insert for all the child account. Now in after insert, I will just do soql having text field value + parentid = null in filter to find out ultimate parent record ---- This is the only trigger based approach I can look at.

Is there any other approach we might be possible with apex without hitting limit?

Comment: see this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/289779/2602) for a SOQL solution that requires only 5 queries to get to 30 levels

Comment: Hi @cropredy thanks for replying. I suggested that too to somone but got back saying that will hit governor limit

Comment: If you have 1000 Accounts, only a tiny fraction of them will have 30 levels so when you need to get ultimate parent you burn 5 SOQL every so often but for most with <=6 parents, you burn one SOQL.  To solve this in one SOQL requires logic to place ultimate parent on each account at run time - catering for deletes and merges -- this is complicated

Comment: The best design depends on the purpose of the code you're writing. What is the intended use of this code?

Comment: @sfdcfox the question was asking in one of online tech coding round. I actually think a lot after the round itself on this. I am sorry if this is not the right platform for to ask interview related question but i did batch class, snippet code but for me its worthless as it still not achieving the expected functionality.