# Getting the top level parent account of an account in hierarchy

Tags: apex, trigger, soql, governorlimits

I have written a class that gets the id of the top level account in the hierarchy of the given account id.

```
public class AccountUtils {
    // Create a Map to hold Account Ids and their parent Ids
    static Map<Id, Id> accountParentMap = new Map<Id, Id>();

    public static void initializeAccountParentMap() {
        // Get all accounts and their parent Ids
        for(Account a : [SELECT Id, ParentId FROM Account]) {
            accountParentMap.put(a.Id, a.ParentId);
        }
    }

    public static Id getTopLevelParentId(Id accountId) {
        // Initialize accountParentMap if not already initialized
        if (accountParentMap.isEmpty()) {
            initializeAccountParentMap();
        }

        Id parentId = accountParentMap.get(accountId);
        while(parentId != null) {
            accountId = parentId;
            parentId = accountParentMap.get(accountId);
        }

        return accountId;
    }
}
```

The only problem with this is that it gets all the accounts at once in a single SOQL query.Is there any way I can optimize the code to avoid hitting number of SOQL Query limit?

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar discussion [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/263444/getting-the-highest-parent-account-in-salesforce-hierarchy-via-soql-apex)

The [last answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/289779/131412) didn't get much attention, but for your use-case, it might be the most practical approach.

You can query 6 levels of the Account hierarchy at a time with the following query:

```
SELECT ParentId, Parent.ParentId, Parent.Parent.ParentId,
Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId, Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId,
Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.ParentId 
FROM Account
WHERE Id = :myAccount.Id
```

- Then, check each ParentId starting at the top.
- If the top is null, go down until you find the first non-null ID.
- If the top isn't null, perform the same query again using the top-level ParentId and repeat these steps.

This seems very likely to find the top-level without hitting query limits. There are perhaps other better suggestions, but they require other customizations and automation beyond updating your Apex class.